# Azure blob trigger Function works fine in visual studio but is not being triggered once published

Tags: function, azure

I have created Azure blob trigger function which run whenever any file is been posted in Azure storage.
It works fine when i ran Azure function from visual studio but it didn't get trigger when i stop visual studio.
Is there any specific setting while deploying it from visual studio ?
Please help

Answer (score 2):

How is your BlobTrigger attribute defined? It requires an application setting which is the connection string to the storage account.

Is your local code also using local storage or is that successfully connecting to blob storage in Azure?

In this example the function uses an application setting called *StorageConnectionAppSetting* which contains the connection string. When the function is published it reads this setting from Function App settings.

`[BlobTrigger("sample-images/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no azure storage connection string in your Azure function application appsetting. If it is that case,we could use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) to do that easily.

```
func azure functionapp publish azurefunctionname --publish-local-settings
```

We also could add the storeage connection string in the Azure function application appsettings directly.

[image]

[image]